# Unity configuration file - GenericArguments violates the constraint of type parameter

Tags: c#, unity-container, config

I'm trying to load the Unity configuration from file Unity.config.
In the implementation of the interfaces used generic-arguments

**My configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

  <assembly name="TestUnity" />
  <namespace name="TestUnity" />

  <container>
    <register type="IGeneric1`2[IGeneric2`1[long], long]" mapTo="ExampleGeneric`2[IGeneric2`1[long], long]">
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```

**Programm code:**

```
public interface IGeneric1<E, in Key> where E : IGeneric2<Key>
{
    void Publish(E msg);
}

public interface IGeneric2<out Key>
{
    Key SourceId { get; }
}
```

public class ExampleGeneric : IGeneric1 where E : IGeneric2
    {
        public void Publish(E msg)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

**Main:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
}
```

**In line**

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration();
```

**displays an error:**

```
GenericArguments[0] "TestUnity.IGeneric2`1[Key]", in "TestUnity.IGeneric1`2[E,Key]" violates the constraint of type paremeter "E"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an implementation of `IGeneric2` in the code and then refer to it in the config file.

**code**

```
class G2 : IGeneric2<long> { ... }
```

**config**

```
<register 
  type="IGeneric1`2[IGeneric2`1[long], long]"
  mapTo="ExampleGeneric`2[G2, long]">
```